# OpenCV VideoWriter Framerate Issue

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I'm attempting to record video from a 1080p webcam into a file. I held a timer up in the video and in every trial the timestamp reported by a video player (VLC is what I used) doesn't sync up with the time in the video. It's always off a few seconds (usually in-video timer is faster than player-reported time).

As seen below, I set up the C++ program to capture video in one thread, and record in another thread. This is working fine as my CPU usage is ~200% (possible max out?). I'm on a Macbook Air w/ OS X 10.8 @ 1.8 GHz Intel Core i7.

I've tried changing the framerate to 15fps and that results in very choppy/slow video. I've also tried setting `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` & `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` to a lower resolution and it results in slow video. It appears that 1080p @ 30fps results in good steady video, but it is still always plays faster than it's supposed to. I've also tried putting in `waitKey(10);` after `record << frame;` but it did not affect anything.

Any recommendations on how to make the video match up in time?

Thanks!
Aakash

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace cv;

void captureFunc(Mat *frame, VideoCapture *capture){
    for(;;){
        // get a new frame from camera
        (*capture) >> (*frame);
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture capture(0); // open the default camera
    if( !capture.isOpened() )  {
        printf("Camera failed to open!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,30); //set capture rate to 30fps
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame; // get first frame for size

    // initialize recording of video
    VideoWriter record("test.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 30, frame.size(), true);
    if( !record.isOpened() ) {
        printf("VideoWriter failed to open!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    boost::thread captureThread(captureFunc, &frame, &capture); //start capture thread

    sleep(1); //just to make sure capture thread is ready

    for(;;)
    {
        // add frame to recorded video
        record << frame;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try with different codecs and with different fps (25 might be a good option).

Comment: I tried 25 FPS and using XVID as the codec. For videos about 1.5 mins it works fine (some parts are a few seconds fast and others slow, so it averages out), but in anything shorter or longer VLC will play the video 3-6 seconds longer than it actually is (ex. Timer in the video shows 5 mins has elapsed, but VLC will play for 5 mins and 6 seconds)

Comment: In my test recording a 5 min video, the time was in sync until after about 3 mins and 10 seconds. Afterwards the gap got up to 6 seconds at times, finishing at around 5 seconds out of sync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved my issue after a bit of debugging; it was an issue with VideoWriter being picky on the rate at which frames were fed to it.

Comment: +1 again for answering the question. But I noticed that you may have a race condition on your solution, since the camera-acquiring thread may refresh the Mat "frame" at the same time VideoWriter is accessing it.

Comment: The writeup is great, but it would be better if you could write it here and just give a link to your website. If you have an url change the information is lost!

Comment: In case the link dies, the write up basically says exactly what you'd expect: that the videowriter "writeFrame()" must be called at exactly the interval of the FPS specified in the format you initialized it with. Makes sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders this doesn't make any sense at all, if I wanted to make a two hour long video for which I could generate the frames in 10 minutes I would have to wait exactly two hours to get my output? veeery wierd.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, indeed. I think the problem is that you write `frame` to your video file, regardless of if it has new content of not. What happens is that you have several video frames in your output, that are identical because you created them from the same input frame. What you need is not to play with timing. What you need is to sync reading and writing, so that you only write when you have a *new* frame. (you might do that with threads, but the simplest way looks like `capture >> frame; process(frame); record << frame:`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync your read and write functions. Your code reads as fast as possible, and writes also as fast as possible. Your output video probably looks slow because writing the output happens faster than reading the input (since `capture >>` is waiting for your camera), and several identical frames are recorded.

Writing without waiting or syncing means you may write the same content several times (what I think is happening here), or lose frames.

If you want to keep having threads, you may, but you will need to make your write process wait until there is something *new* to write.

Likewise to avoid losing frames or writing corrupted frames, you need the read process to wait until writing is done, so that `frame` can be safely overwritten.

Since the threads need to wait for each other anyway, there's little point in threads at all.

I'd rather recommend this much simpler way:

```
for (;;) {
    capture >> frame;
    process(frame);  // whatever smart you need
    record << frame;
}
```

If you need parallelism, you'll need much more complex sync mechanism, and maybe some kind of fifo for your frames.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As Gauthier wrote, there is no mechanism in the code shown to ensure there is one and only one write per read so each frame i being written an unpredictable number of times.