# OpenCV: Should the write from VideoWriter run in an independent thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm writing a program that reads multiple webcams, stitches the pictures together and saves them into a video file.

1. Should i use threads to capture the images and to write the resulting large image into a file?
2. If yes, should i use c+11 or boost?
3. Do you maybe have some simple example code which shows how to avoid racing conditions?

I already found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091975/opencv-videowriter-framerate-issue) which uses threads for write but it doesn't seem to avoid racing conditions.

pseudocode of my program:

```
camVector //vector with cameras
VideoWriter outputVideo //outputs the video

while(true){
    for(camera:camVector){
        camera.grab() //send signal to grab picture
    }
    picVector = getFrames(camVector) //collect frames of all cameras into a Vector

    Mat bigImg = stitchPicTogether(picVector)

    outputVideo.write(bigImg)
}
```

Comment: About race conditions: can you detail your stiching? Is it simply tiling or does it involves blending at the edges?

Comment: when in doubt, avoid threads. (btw, the capture is already running a seperate thread for img retrieval)

Comment: @berak: when in doubt, avoid *** can be said about anything! Hardware constraints dictate that parallelism is here to stay, so better use it ;)

Comment: @Antoine: The `Mat bigImg ` is seperated into several not overlapping `Mat subimg`. The captured frames are copied via `remap` (using a affine Transformation) into the correct subImg parts of bigImg. After the copying is done for all frames the frame can be saved.

Comment: Cool, if there's no overlapping, then you can safely do the `remap`s in parallel.

Comment: m( i haven't thought about that. Yeah, i will definitely do the getFrames+remap in parallel. Any thoughts on the write though? Is it also in parallel?

Comment: Yes, the write can be in parallel since there's no overlap. Basically, your `cv::Mat` is a chunk of memory to which several threads can write safely write as long as the writes don't overlap. If I understood you correctly, that's the case because of the `subimg`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I'd do:

```
camVector //vector with cameras
VideoWriter outputVideo //outputs the video

for(camera:camVector) camera.grab(); // request first frame

while(true){
    parallel for(camera:camVector) {
        frame = getFrame(camera);
        pasteFrame(/* destination */ bigImg,
                   /* geometry    */ geometry[camera],
                   /* source      */ frame
                  );
        camera.grab(); // request next frame, so the webcam driver can start working
                       // while you write to disk
    }
    outputVideo.write(bigImg)
}
```

This way stiching is done in parallel, and if your webcam drivers have different timing, you can begin stiching what you recieved from one webcam while you wait for the other webcam's frame.

About implementation, you could simply go with [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), already used in OpenCV, something like `#pragma omp parallel`. If you prefer something more C++ like, give Intel [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) a try, it's cool.

Or as you said, you could go with native C++11 threads or boost. Choosing between the two mainly depend on your work environment: if you intend to work with older compiler, boost is safer.

In all cases, no locking is required, except a join at the end, to wait for all threads to finish their work.

If your bottleneck is writing the output, the limitting factor is either disk IO or video compression speed. For disk, you can try changing codec and/or compressing more. For compression speed, have a look at GPU codecs like [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk).

Comment: I did that, the only question open is whether i should do the write in a parallel thread too. I'm not sure how OpenCV handles that stuff.

Comment: OpenCV works row by row, and for sub images, it changes the header so that only a specific range is updated in a range of selected lines. If the ranges don't overlap, the writes won't conflict.

Comment: We have a slight misunderstanding. I mean the write of the `bigImg` onto the hard drive using `VideoWriter`. In my pseudocode the line `outputVideo.write(bigImg)`

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding you. Writing the file from multiple files would be challenging, indeed! OpenCV is just a wrapper around libs like ffmpeg, directX, etc. **But** you can pipeline disk writes and webcam drivers request, I edited my answer accordingly.