# OpenCV VideoWriter won't set properly the FPS

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

In my program, I'm reading from a webcam or a video file, via OpenCV and displaying it via Qt.
I get the fps from the video properties and set the timer accordingly.

I have no problem reading the videos, the fps calibration is good (since the webcam show 0fps, I set it to 30)
But when I record the images, I set the output video's fps to the same as the original video, yet, when I read it in VLC or even Windows Media Player the video is accelerated.

The most curious thing is when I play the recorded video in my program, the fps is good, and the video isn't accelerated.

---

Here's how I do it :

```
Constructor()
{
    // Initializing the video resources
    cv::VideoCapture capture;
    cv::VideoWriter writer;
    cv::Mat frame;
    int fps;

    if (webcam)
    {
        capture.open(0);
        fps = 30;
    }
    else
    {
        capture.open(inputFilePath);
        fps = this->capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    }
    // .avi
    writer = cv::VideoWriter(outputFilePath, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, frame.size());

    // Defining the refresh timer;
    QTimer timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateFeed()));
    this->timer->start(1000 / fps);
}

updateFeed()
{
    // ... display the image in a QLabel ... at a reasonnable speed.
    writer.write(frame);
}
```

---

Now is there anything I do wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV VideoWriter Framerate Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091975/opencv-videowriter-framerate-issue)

Comment: If you'd read more than just the title, you'd have seen that the problem is different as I already write images using a threaded timer.

Comment: I have read more than the title, because I was running into a similar issue writing an OpenCV video and was looking for a solution. For me it was caused by a memory leak though. Does your problem occur with both webcam and files? Where is the code that updates `frame`?

Comment: I edited the code so you can explicitely see where my code update.
Please note that this exact code won't work as I simplified it for people to understand it better.