# opencv write video without manually timing the frames

Tags: opencv, video

So it seems according to this answer, that the `opencv` `VideoWriter` is not really smart (or well, maybe not suited for the purpose I would like to use it) about handling frames. According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091975/opencv-videowriter-framerate-issue) of this question, you have to time your frames manually, thus the creation of a two hour long video will take two hours.

If you want to check, the following script creates a 100 fps VideoWriter and writes 1500 frames to it, which should be exactly 15 seconds long, but ends up being 26 seconds or so.

**EDIT:** The code was edited to create six videos, with 3 fps-s intended to be 15 and 30 seconds long. The table at the end of the question was made using this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

for fps in [20,50,100]:
    vWriter = cv2.VideoWriter("test" +str(fps)+".avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('P','I','M','1'),fps,(500,500),True)
    y = 0
    for x in range(15*fps):
        img = np.zeros((500,500,3)).astype(np.uint8)
        cv2.circle(img,(250,int(y)),5,(255,255,255),-1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        y += 500/15/fps
        vWriter.write(img)



for fps in [20,50,100]:
    vWriter = cv2.VideoWriter("test2_" +str(fps)+".avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('P','I','M','1'),fps,(500,500),True)
    y = 0
    ts = time.time()
    for x in range(30*fps):
        img = np.zeros((500,500,3)).astype(np.uint8)
        cv2.circle(img,(250,int(y)),5,(255,255,255),-1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        y += 500/30/fps
        vWriter.write(img)
```

Is there any workaround for this? This manual timing of frames seems really cumbersome. Or if there are no workarounds, any other cross-platform video creation method that you can recommend, that does not suffer from this problem?

I made a little test with different lengths and framerates, I checked 20, 50 and 100 fps with 15 and 30 second long videos (intended length, so I generated 15 or 30 times the fps frames).

```
FPS   intended_length   actual_length

20    15                12
50    15                15
100   15                25
20    30                25
50    30                30
100   30                50
```

Looks like the 50 fps is the one where it gets it correctly, but why?

Comment: no idea why the video shouldnt be of 15 seconds duration. maybe your player/harsware cant handle 100fps? did you try to .close the videowriter after processing? did you try the same for lower framerates?

Comment: I added a little table with different times and framerates. How do you close the videowriter?

Comment: `VideoCapture::release()`. I don't understand your table... If you feed 500 frames to a 20 fps video, the video should have a length of 25 seconds, doesn't it?!? Ah ok, you have an input video with a specified length. Do you know which FPS were present in the input video? If you want to reduce the fps you have to drop frames. If you want to increase the fps you have to add additional frames. Looks like your input video has 50 fps.

Comment: I edited the question with the code for the six videos. For a 15s intended length with 20 fps I generate 15*20 frames as you can see. That's why I don't get it, why it works only for the 50 fps :)

Comment: release() didn't change anything :(

Comment: did you try different codecs? maybe mpeg1 doesn't support all kind of framerates? If you use windows, what does file details tell you about video codec, resolution, fps and length?

Comment: brilliant, it is a codec issue, changing to `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','2','6','4')` gives correct 30 and 15 fps videos.